# Apache Accessing System Environment Variables (for Log File Location)

Tags: apache-2.2, log-files, environment-variables

Is there a way to let Apache access the *system* environment variables? I know it has its own environment and can pass them to spawned processes like PHP, but is there a way to let the server itself access the system’s variables?

In this specific case, what I want to do is to configure Apache to put log files in a folder pointed to by an environment variable (let’s use `TEMP` as an easy example). Unfortunately I cannot find anything helpful because it is a somewhat unusual task. Using the following won’t work:

```
CustomLog "%{TEMP}e/access.log" common
```

The [man page](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/env.html) says to use the OS to modify system variables, but it says nothing about *accessing* them.

Is there a way for Apache to access system variables? Is there a way to put log files in a variable location? (I am willing to update Apache if necessary.)

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish with the system environment variables?

Comment: @ShaneMadden, like I said in the second paragraph, I want to put the log files in a place pointed to by an env-var.

Comment: What I want is to put the logs somewhere variable. That’s it. I am building a portable WAMP stack that can be run from a flash-drive. It is working great, but putting log files on flash-memory is bad because it will wear it out unnecessarily fast due to constant writes. I want to put the log files somewhere on the hard-drive and then when the server is shut down, zip them up and copy them to the flash-drive. I do not want to hard-code a path since the whole goal is to be able to run it from any system, hence the env-var (e.g., `temp`, `userprofile`, etc.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can replace a system environment variable into the config:

```
CustomLog "${ENVVAR}/access.log" common
```

But, if that environment variable isn't set, the text is left alone (which will make for invalid syntax).  See [here](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/configuring.html#syntax).

A better option would probably be to include a file (`Include /path/to/logging.conf`) with the logging config, and change it as needed.

Comment: BINGO! It works beautifully (and you said it wasn’t possible ☺). It’s odd that it is hidden away like that. I tried finding it with Google but could not find it without getting too specific with stuff that would require already knowing the answer.

Comment: @Synetech Yeah, I was thinking of the `Define` behavior in 2.4, which uses the same replacement syntax.. definitely not easy info to find.